# Making an updating winform multi threaded

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I have been breaking my head over this for a long time now and I can't seem to find how to solve this. Simply put I need to present Parallel programming to my class and i am making a demo that clearly shows the diffrence between single threaded and multi threaded.

First the program takes a screenshot and loads that in this class into a `bitmap`.
Then it loads the winform with a `picturebox` called `screenshot`. Next it does `Form1_Load` and loads the screenshot into the `picturebox`.
Then `Form1_Shown` Runs the for loop which just scrambles the pixels around based on a randomizer and updates the image from the left to the right.

example: http://gyazo.com/ab04583bb33de59d08407886da1c4870

This all works. 
I now want to make it so that the screenshot is being updated from the left to the middle by the first thread, and from the middle to the right with the second thread.

But when i put it in 2 separate threads it says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

The error implies I am making illegal cross thread calls. Particulary on `screenshot` and probably also on `mybitmap`.
Visual studio helps me by linking me to ["How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHInvalidOperation.WinForms.IllegalCrossThreadCall);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

But i am not getting any wiser out of this information which is probably because i am not that fluent with the C# terminology yet.

How should i approach/fix this ?

This is the class where everything happens (except taking the screenshot):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScreenOutput
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    PictureBox screenshot;
    Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@".\screenshot.jpg");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int Xcount;
    private int Ycount;
    private int maxXValue = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 1;

    private int maxXValueT1 = 960;
    private int maxXValueT2 = 1919;

    private int maxYValue = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 1;
    private int maxYValueT1 = 539;
    private int maxYValueT2 = 1079;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        screenshot.Image = myBitmap;
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread startThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thread1));
        Thread startThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thread2));
        startThread1.Start();
        startThread2.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000); //waiting for completion
        startThread1.Abort();
        startThread2.Abort();

        //this is how it would work without multithreading
        /*Random random = new Random();
        for (Xcount = 0; Xcount < maxXValue; Xcount++)
        {

            screenshot.Refresh();
            for (Ycount = 0; Ycount < maxYValue; Ycount++)
            {
                int calculatedX = Xcount + random.Next(0, maxXValue);
                if (calculatedX > maxXValue) calculatedX = maxXValue;
                myBitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, myBitmap.GetPixel(calculatedX, Ycount));

            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);*/
        Application.Exit();
    }

    public void thread1()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (Xcount = 0; Xcount < maxXValueT1; Xcount++)
        {

            screenshot.Refresh();
            for (Ycount = 0; Ycount < maxYValueT1; Ycount++)
            {
                int calculatedX = Xcount + random.Next(0, maxXValueT1);
                if (calculatedX > maxXValue) calculatedX = maxXValueT1;
                myBitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, myBitmap.GetPixel(calculatedX, Ycount));
            }
        }
    }

    public void thread2()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (Xcount = 0; Xcount < maxXValueT2; Xcount++)
        {

            screenshot.Refresh();
            for (Ycount = 0; Ycount < maxYValueT2; Ycount++)
            {
                int calculatedX = Xcount + random.Next(0, maxXValueT2);
                if (calculatedX > maxXValueT2) calculatedX = maxXValueT2;
                myBitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, myBitmap.GetPixel(calculatedX, Ycount));
            }
        }           
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ever consider using a `Timer`

Comment: @MethodMan not sure how i would solve the problem with a timer ? 
I am still very inexperienced to this.

Comment: It is unlikely SO can help you more that linked article... There are many similar questions on SO too but obviously all of them talk about the same fix - you may get answers more useful to you if you scope the question down to particular concepts you don't understand from the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to Invoke the GUI thread.
I prefer the following solution.
Using a Form member (*'screenshot' in this case*) check to see if InvokeRequired = true. If so then Invoke a delegate using that members BeginInvoke() function as the following example demonstrates:

```
private void ScreenshotRefresh()
 {         
     if(screenshot.InvokeRequired)
     {
         screenshot.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.ScreenshotRefresh));    
     }
     else
     {
         screenshot.Refresh();
     }
 }
```

Comment: So then i would be only calling the Screenshot refresh method in the threads ? (if i would be using the second example?)

Comment: Correct, within your thread functions change
    __screenshot.Refresh();__
to
    __ScreenshotRefresh();__   Also, you MIGHT have an issue with multi-thread actions running concurrently on myBitmap.  There are threadsafe functions that might need to be called.

Comment: Okey, Probably i didn't get this part yet. But now VS says: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInVoke' and no extension method 'BeginInVoke' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ah yeah that what i thought as well about the mybitmap. Stilll not sure how that works. Is it the same way as you proposed to solve it with the `screenshot` ?

Comment: Ow haha, happens to me aswell.. alot :).

Anyway, you are right, now i have the problem on the `mybitmap`
It is partially working if i disable the `mybitmap.setpixel` in one of the two threads. I guess he doesn't want to set the pixels at the same time

Comment: Multithreaded work on an image might require bypassing the image class functions and working directly with the image data.   Take a look at this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx This is a much more complex subject beyond the scope of the original question.  You will need to research MultiThreaded Image manipulation.  Perhaps since its just for demonstration purposes you could just use two images and two pictureboxes?

Comment: that might an easier solution which i was already trying to implement thanks.

Comment: One more thing though. With your solution the image is not scrolling like it was before from left to right. Like you can see here single threaded. http://gyazo.com/a828a24ea942aa88fae1e949889c2d61

Now This is the second thread updating the right part of the screen but in one update http://gyazo.com/a2ac3c375bdf7e296c25c125d16bad82

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70348/discussion-between-don-and-kevin).